# Select onselect all disable other values - PHP and jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have `select` box with `multiple` option in my project. The code is below

```
<select name='sendto[]' id='sendto' multiple required>
   <option value='branchstaff'>Branch Staff</option>
   <option value='manager'>Manager</option>
   <option value='cashier'>Cashier</option>
   <option value='hostaff'>Head Office Staff</option>
   <option value='all'>All of Above</option>
</select>
```

I am using jQuery in this project. Now I want to select some values to send message. How can I deselect all other values when I click `All of Above`

Comment: @Pekka That is also fine, but `value='all'` should not be posted

Comment: $('sendto').find('option').attr('selected','selected');

Comment: For UI experience, would be better to set the `All` outside the select box, not as option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#sendto').change(function() {
  alert($('option:selected', this).val())
  if ($('option:selected', this).val() === 'all') {
    $("select[multiple] option").prop("selected", "selected");
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='sendto[]' id='sendto' multiple required>
  <option value='branchstaff'>Branch Staff</option>
  <option value='manager'>Manager</option>
  <option value='cashier'>Cashier</option>
  <option value='hostaff'>Head Office Staff</option>
  <option value='all'>All of Above</option>
</select>
```

```
    $('#sendto').change(function () {
    if ($('option:selected', this).val() == 'all') {
        $("select[multiple] option").prop("selected", "selected");
    }
})

<select name='sendto[]' id='sendto' multiple required>
   <option value='branchstaff'>Branch Staff</option>
   <option value='manager'>Manager</option>
   <option value='cashier'>Cashier</option>
   <option value='hostaff'>Head Office Staff</option>
   <option value='all'>All of Above</option>
</select>
```

Try this

Comment: `val()` returns an array in this case

Comment: even if i put in `'option:selected', this` ? @A.Wolff

Comment: Oops sorry, i missed it :)  But in that case, would match only first value of selected option. BTW, if `All` selected, OP doens't want it to be passed to server

Comment: @Ranjan happy coding mate glad to help

Comment: @Ranjan It doesn't work if any previous option already selected

Comment: @A.Wolff if i choose one and select all i get all im sorry please check

Comment: @Pekka I tested it here: http://jsfiddle.net/c0jh18f8/  And `val()` return only first matched element value. EDIT: i'd use that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/c0jh18f8/1/  And to hanlde not passing `All`: http://jsfiddle.net/c0jh18f8/2/

Comment: @A.Wolff it works now?please feel free to give comment to make the answer correct i dont want to give incorrect answer

Comment: @A.Wolff  jsfiddle.net/c0jh18f8/2 code worked perfectly the way I wanted

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
$("option").click(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "All of Above") {
        $(this).siblings().removeAttr("selected");
    }
});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zaeo3qr3/)

Comment: i suggestion to use change when using select

Comment: FYI, chrome doesn't handle any mouse event on `option` element

Comment: @A.Wolff Then the above JSFiddle should not be working right? :)

Comment: @AhsN My bad, multiple select let mouse event on option to be bound, sorry! And +1 because you are answering ` How can I deselect all ` even it doesn't make sense regarding clicking on a `All` option

Comment: @A.Wolff No prob :D U just taught me that single-select doesn't registers any events for `option` element, which implies why we mostly use onchange event on the `select` element usually. Cheers! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option[value="all"]').on('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().find('option').attr('selected','selected');
  $(this).removeAttr('selected');
});
```

Comment: i suggestion to use change when using select

Answer (score 0):

try below

```js
$('#sendto option[value="all"]').on('click',function(){
    $('#sendto').find('option').attr('selected','selected');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='sendto[]' id='sendto' multiple required>
   <option value='branchstaff'>Branch Staff</option>
   <option value='manager'>Manager</option>
   <option value='cashier'>Cashier</option>
   <option value='hostaff'>Head Office Staff</option>
   <option value='all'>All of Above</option>
</select>
```